# Changing property of input field using java script

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

```js
function random() {
                    document.querySelector('[name="stationerytype[]"]').value = ""
  
                    var a = document.getElementById('purpose').value;
                    if (a === "Meeting") {
                    var datalist = "datalist1";
                    } else if (a === "Departmental") {
                    var datalist = "datalist2";
                    }
    
                    document.querySelector('[name="stationerytype[]"]').setAttribute("list", datalist)

                    }
          
          var options = document.querySelectorAll(".option1");
            options.forEach(function(option) {
              option.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
                calculatingMinimunQuantity(option);
              });
              option.nextElementSibling.addEventListener('change', evt => {
                if (+evt.target.value < +evt.target.min) evt.target.value = evt.target.min
              });
            });
            
            function calculatingMinimunQuantity(option) {
              var minimum = 0, step1 = 0;
              var value = option.value;
              if (value === "PENCIL") {
                minimum = "5";
                step1="5";
              } else if (value === "NOTEPAD") {
                minimum = "10";
                step1="10";
              }
              //   getting the quantity input field
              option.nextElementSibling.setAttribute("min", minimum);
              option.nextElementSibling.setAttribute("step", step1);
              
        }
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-6">
                    <label for="purpose">Purpose</label>
                    <select type="text" name="purpose" id="purpose" class="form-control" onchange="random()" required />
                    <option ></option>
                    <option value="Meeting">Meeting</option>
                    <option value="Departmental">Departmental</option>
                    </select>
                    </div>
                  
        <td><input  type="text" name="stationerytype[]" id="stationerytype" class="option1 form-control" autocomplete="off"  required>
                <datalist id="datalist1" >
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="MEETING PEN">MEETING PEN</option>
                <option value="NOTEPAD">NOTEPAD</option>
                <option value="PLASTIC FOLDER">PLASTIC FOLDER</option>
                <option value="PENCIL">PENCIL</option>
                </datalist> 
                
                <datalist id="datalist2" >
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="A4 GREEN REAM">A4 GREEN REAM</option>
                <option value="A4 WHITE REAM">A4 WHITE REAM</option>
                <option value="BMO LETTER HEAD">BMO LETTER HEAD</option>
                </datalist>
          </td>
                            
                    
                            
        <td><input type="NUMBER" name="stationeryqtyrqst[]" id="stationeryqtyrqst" class="form-control" required ></td>
```

I have a form that has two fields stationerytype and stationeryrqstqty.The stationeryrqstqtyfield of the form accepts the number. The minimum number which can be entered in this field(QTY) depends upon the value of the stationerytype field i.e. If the stationerytype field value is 'pencil' then the minimum value property of the stationeryrqstqty field should be 5 and if it is 'notepad' then the minimum property of the stationeryrqstqty field should be 10. I am doing it by the given code but it's not working.it gives always 1,2,3.......

```
<td><input type="text"  name="slno" value= "<?php echo $i; ?>" class="form-control " readonly ></td>
    
    <td><input  type="text" name="stationerytype[]" id="stationerytype" class="option1 form-control" autocomplete="off"  required>
            <datalist id="datalist1" >
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="MEETING PEN">MEETING PEN</option>
            <option value="NOTEPAD">NOTEPAD</option>
            <option value="PLASTIC FOLDER">PLASTIC FOLDER</option>
            <option value="PENCIL">PENCIL</option>
            </datalist> 
            
            <datalist id="datalist2" >
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="A4 GREEN REAM">A4 GREEN REAM</option>
            <option value="A4 WHITE REAM">A4 WHITE REAM</option>
            <option value="BMO LETTER HEAD">BMO LETTER HEAD</option>
            </datalist>
      </td>
                        
                
                        
    <td><input type="NUMBER" name="stationeryqtyrqst[]" id="stationeryqtyrqst" class="form-control" required ></td>
    <script>
    var options = document.querySelectorAll(".option1");
        options.forEach(function(option) {
          option.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
            calculatingMinimunQuantity(option);
          });
          option.nextElementSibling.addEventListener('change', evt => {
            if (+evt.target.value < +evt.target.min) evt.target.value = evt.target.min
          });
        });
        
        function calculatingMinimunQuantity(option) {
          var minimum = 0, step1 = 0;
          var value = option.value;
          if (value === "PENCIL") {
            minimum = "5";
            step1="5";
          } else if (value === "NOTEPAD") {
            minimum = "10";
            step1="10";
          }
          //   getting the quantity input field
          option.nextElementSibling.setAttribute("min", minimum);
          option.nextElementSibling.setAttribute("step", step1);
          
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: I like your name `stationeryrqstqty`. I hope I never have to type or read that. Why not `stationery-request-quantity`? Or `stationeryRequestQuantity`? Why the unnecessary abbreviations?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Thanks for your suggestion. Can you help me in this code

Comment: I tried to run your code to see what might be wrong, but the HTML is quite invalid. I added the table tags, but now the [datalists](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist) don't attach themselves to anything and they contain more things than your code will process. To many errors to even start looking what could be wrong with the Javascript.

Comment: @kil Please provide a working snippet using sites like [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net). It was hard to actually make it work to start with. If we can't run it, it will be hard to debug as well. Also, for naming conventions, as stated by KIKOSoftware, avoid unnecessary abbreviations. It will be hard for others and will add extra time for debugging.

Comment: @HimanshuBansal i have uploaded snippet kindly look into that

Comment: @kil Sorry for the delay. I was on vacation.  Shared the code.

Answer (score 0):

The below lines are setting the attributes to the datalist tag and not the input tag.

```
option.nextElementSibling.setAttribute("min", minimum);
option.nextElementSibling.setAttribute("step", step1);
```

[image]

I changed it to select the correct tag and set default value as minimum:

```
let quantity_field = document.getElementById("stationeryqtyrqst");
    if(quantity_field){
    quantity_field.setAttribute("min", minimum);
    quantity_field.setAttribute("step", step1);
    quantity_field.value = minimum;
}
```

Attaching snippet for reference:

```js
function random() {
                    document.querySelector('[name="stationerytype[]"]').value = ""
  
                    var a = document.getElementById('purpose').value;
                    if (a === "Meeting") {
                    var datalist = "datalist1";
                    } else if (a === "Departmental") {
                    var datalist = "datalist2";
                    }
    
                    document.querySelector('[name="stationerytype[]"]').setAttribute("list", datalist)

                    }
          
          var options = document.querySelectorAll(".option1");
            options.forEach(function(option) {
              option.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
                calculatingMinimunQuantity(option);
              });
              option.nextElementSibling.addEventListener('change', evt => {
                if (+evt.target.value < +evt.target.min) evt.target.value = evt.target.min
              });
            });
            
            function calculatingMinimunQuantity(option) {
              var minimum = 0, step1 = 0;
              var value = option.value;
              if (value === "PENCIL") {
                minimum = "5";
                step1="5";
              } else if (value === "NOTEPAD") {
                minimum = "10";
                step1="10";
              }
              //   updated the below code to get the correct field and set default values.
              let quantity_field = document.getElementById("stationeryqtyrqst");
              if(quantity_field){
                quantity_field.setAttribute("min", minimum);
                quantity_field.setAttribute("step", step1);
                quantity_field.value = minimum;
              }
              
              
              
        }
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-6">
                    <label for="purpose">Purpose</label>
                    <select type="text" name="purpose" id="purpose" class="form-control" onchange="random()" required />
                    <option ></option>
                    <option value="Meeting">Meeting</option>
                    <option value="Departmental">Departmental</option>
                    </select>
                    </div>
                  
        <td><input  type="text" name="stationerytype[]" id="stationerytype" class="option1 form-control" autocomplete="off"  required>
                <datalist id="datalist1" >
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="MEETING PEN">MEETING PEN</option>
                <option value="NOTEPAD">NOTEPAD</option>
                <option value="PLASTIC FOLDER">PLASTIC FOLDER</option>
                <option value="PENCIL">PENCIL</option>
                </datalist> 
                
                <datalist id="datalist2" >
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="A4 GREEN REAM">A4 GREEN REAM</option>
                <option value="A4 WHITE REAM">A4 WHITE REAM</option>
                <option value="BMO LETTER HEAD">BMO LETTER HEAD</option>
                </datalist>
          </td>
                            
                    
                            
        <td><input type="NUMBER" name="stationeryqtyrqst[]" id="stationeryqtyrqst" class="form-control" required ></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wont get in to details, of your workaround or anything, just hints on how to set min, max on an input,
using vanilla js, you can do this:

```
document.querySelector("input[name='stationeryqtyrqst[]']").setAttribute("min",10)
```

change the selector to whatever you want to, and update it accordingly,
this should work for input type=number, for inputs of other types, you should implement some value check on input/keydown/keyup event.

you can set max the same way.